# Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53

Tags: wordpress, installation, failure

I am just trying to install on a WordPress platform and it said OK for all the checks and fairly sure that everything is okay.  After running with Install button, I get this error and if I click in the WordPress admin menu CiviCRM:
No idea what I have wrong as DB/PHP etc are all in order.  I followed the wiki article exactly.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA. thrown in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53

I am using PHP 5.6, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper ; and Ubuntu 16.04 which I am fairly sure is configured properly as Wordpress runs fine.  I followed every step.  I am a bit discouraged.

I wanted to just get an empty version of Civi going to test out things so as to later migrate from a Drupal environment.  Any Help?

Explain?. It's Ubuntu, php mysql.... What do you mean?. I installed WordPress... And everything works for that.  I installed Civi as a plugin and can't get it running ...I get this error. What else do you want to  know? The others are drupal installs. This is Unix instance on aws. Not sure what you mean explain?  The tables were created. But I can't run plug-in. Ubuntu 16, PHP 5.6 and mysql  5.7

Comment: There are at least 3 other Q+A on here about InstallationCanary. It will help if you can explain what differs in your case to those ones.

Comment: Explain?. It's Ubuntu, php mysql.... What do you mean?. I installed WordPress... And everything works for that.  I installed Civi as a plugin and can't get it running ...I get this error. What else do you want to  know? The others are drupal installs. This is Unix instance on aws. Not sure what you mean explain?  The tables were created. But I can't run plug-in. Ubuntu 16, PHP 5.6 and mysql  5.7

Comment: @PhotoLarry Stack Exchange is designed so that the best answer to a problem is always found in one place.  That means that if your problem is identical to a problem someone else has already asked about, it's best not to ask your own question.  What Pete is suggesting by "explain" is to look at the other questions people have asked about installation canary errors on Stack Exchange, and please edit your question to explain what's different about your situation, if anything.  This helps ensure that people giving freely of their time to help out aren't answering the same question over and over.

Comment: Nobody answered over and over or at all. That's why I posted this.  Nothing in those threads helped me at all. And nobody had answered them in years. What I did is Jerry appropriate.

Comment: This was solved by installing a different version 4.7.22

Answer (score 3):

The answer above about deleting the civicrm_install_canary table and the civicrm folder in uploads almost worked for me, except that php timed out ~30 seconds after the green 'successful installation' message appeared. I tweaked max_execution_time in php.ini to 360, deactivated CiviCRM, re-deleted the table and folder, then reactivated and re-installed - this time it finished gracefully and opened CiviCRM.

I am installing CiviCRM on a testing server (running on my laptop), which is a little slower than most working servers, but is configured to show errors one might not otherwise see.  The cleanup and/or 'reset' process that runs after the 'successful installation' message appears to take so much time that it is likely timing out even on some working servers, which results in not finishing the process and leaving the canary table in place.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the understanding around this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after installing, uninstalling, then reinstalling. I couldn't install it the second time because the uninstall wasn't very clean. I recommend deleting or renaming the civicrm folder under the uploads folder.  Then, you need to delete the civicirm_install_canary table from the database. After that, try to reinstall it again. I was able to successfully reinstall after doing those 2 things

Comment: I'll try this. I saw no help in other threads at all. No steps and nothing at all.  Just the error without any suggestions of what's gone wrong.  I'm not liking Civi / developers since so few seem to want to help with something as simple as installation that shouldn't yield errors on a fresh server with new wordpress and nothing special in configuration. I made virtual server and am trying from there to install then migrate from a drupal installation later  this year

Answer (score 0):

I had to simply drop the civicrm_install_canary table and my install roared to life.