# Failure to install CiviCRM on a clean new Wordpress site, running on Debian Jessie. Installation activation went to a blank page

Tags: wordpress, installation, failure

Using Let's Encrypt for ssl, no problems with WordPress.  Installation and plugin activation for CiviCRM  led to a blank page. Apache2 log looks like this:

```
[Wed Jul 05 13:58:40.895212 2017] [ssl: warn] [pid 30451] AH01909: p:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 05 13:58:40.922645 2017] [ssl: warn] [pid 30452] AH01909: p:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 05 13:58:40.924775 2017] [mpm_prefork: notice] [pid 30452] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.2l configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 05 13:58:40.924794 2017] [core: notice] [pid 30452] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jul 05 14:04:22.208994 2017] [:error] [pid 30478] [client 176.126.252.12:40655] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. 
[Wed Jul 05 14:06:40.022932 2017] [:error] [pid 30464] [client 176.126.252.12:60919] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA.\n\n  thrown in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53, referer
```

Checked ownership and permissions on plugin files.  Nothing unusual there.

Comment: there seem to be a number of tickets re WP installation currently. Can you pls check if there are common characteritistics?

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19329/fatal-error-uncaught-crm-core-exception-0-found-installation-canary?s=2|0.0000

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19200/fatal-error-uncaught-crm-core-exception-civi-core-installationcanary-php-on-li?s=3|0.0000

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/installation-error?s=4|0.0000

Comment: One thing did come up on installation:  first I unzipped the civiCRM pluggin in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins  and tried to install from there - but the WP admin plugin page would not find the plugin there.  When I moved the plugin files to /var/www/wp-content/plugins, the admin plugin page then found the plugin and began to install.  Though the CiviCRM label  does appear at the top of the menu band on the left side of wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status, when I click on that graphic I am directed to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM, which is a blank page, which does not clear.

Comment: So, my situation is similar to issue 19200. Couple of differences though.  I'm using php7.0, (it is not the default on Jessie).  Also mariadb, which IS standard on Jessie.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that I am using the latest WP and latest CiviCRM, which is 4.7.19