# installation canary Error Message upon installation

Tags: error, civicrm-home

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong?  thanks[image: ![this is the error message I got upon installation]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bVnM.png)

update:  this is what it says inside the php file manager: public_html/democratizetheentperprise/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civi/core/installationcanary.php

what do I do with it?

http://civicrm.org/licensing        |
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
 */

namespace Civi\Core;

use Civi\Core\Event\SystemInstallEvent;

/**
 * Class InstallationCanary
 * @package Civi\Core
 */
class InstallationCanary {

/**
   * Check whether the install has run before.
   *
   * Circa v4.7.betaX, we introduced a new mechanism for tracking installation
   * and firing a post-install event. However, it's fairly difficult to test the
   * edge-cases directly, so this canary should fire if there are any problems
   * in the design/implementation of the installation-tracker.
   *
   * This should not exist. It should be removed in a future version.
   *
   * @param \Civi\Core\Event\SystemInstallEvent $event
   * @throws \CRM_Core_Exception
   */
  public static function check(SystemInstallEvent $event) {
    if (\CRM_Core_DAO::checkTableExists('civicrm_install_canary')) {
      throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Found installation canary. This suggests that something went wrong with tracking installation process. Please post to forum or JIRA.");
    }
    \Civi::log()->info('Creating canary table');
    \CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('CREATE TABLE civicrm_install_canary (id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB');
  }

}

Answer (score 2):

The message itself gives a quite bit of info that the installation wasn't done correctly or there would be something missing from the process. Make sure you followed [the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/master/install/drupal7/) correctly while installing CiviCRM.

I've seen this on doing a page relaod while the installation is still in progress.

If you think the process is done correctly and just want to get rid if this error - try deleting `civicrm_install_canary` table from the database and reload the page.

Comment: can you kindly tell me where to locate this file to delete it?

Comment: in my FTP account to delete it or inside the PHP file manager? I follow this path: public_html/democratizetheenteprise/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civi/core... then what?

Comment: This is not a file - `civicrm_install_canary` is a table which will be present in your database. It is basically automatically deleted after a successful installation. Check if it is still present in your DB and delete it manually if it is.

Comment: thank you.  please explain very clearly how I go about locating the file in the database- for someone who has never done this before.  thank you.

Comment: ok - Note that I'm not talking about any *file*. `civicrm_install_canary` is a table which is present in your database. If you are working on your local, you can open phpmyAdmin and delete this table from your database from the user interface OR execute this query in your DB - `DROP TABLE civicrm_install_canary`. If you are not able to do this, may be you should ask your technician or DB administrator do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea about what might be happening.  I had the same canary error message trying to install civicrm on my testing server (which is set to display errors one may not see on a live server).

After the green 'successful installation' message appears CiviCRM apparently runs a cleanup and/or reset process before opening up the home CiviCRM admin page.  That process takes a long time and may cause php to timeout if the default is set to 30 seconds in php.ini.  If the process times out then the canary table is never deleted and you get an error message of this sort:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\Don\Documents\webs\Spectrumz\blog\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php on line 2202

My testing server is running on a laptop, so it is likely slower than most working servers, but some may be slow enough that the post-installation process times out. Increase max_execution_time in php.ini if you control your server.

Then see this post, which describes deleting the installation canary table and the uploads/civicrm folder, then reactivating and re-installing: [Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: Civi/Core/InstallationCanary.php on line 53](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19200/fatal-error-uncaught-crm-core-exception-civi-core-installationcanary-php-on-li)